# CSS Issue - Jquery Lightbox size resized when clicking next/previous button

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Good day guys. I just want to ask some idea from pros here about the **next/previous-transition (resized) issue** with a jquery lightbox plugin.

**Original look** when an image is loaded:[image: image of fully loaded image]

The **resized look** when next/previous arrow is clicked:

[image]

I suspect that I made some css modification with the plugin's default styles when im still customizing the look of the like box.

---

I used the latest **Wordpress Jquery Lightbox**(Latest version plugin)

The site is available in: **`http://204.197.252.143/~themainr/`**

The jquery lighbox is in the middle part of the page. One of the links(underlined) will open the popup box:

[image]

---

> **Q:** I just wanna ask if what is the best CSS work around for this issue that the responsive part of the lightbox will not be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i figured out an answer to my problem myself however i don't know if this is the best solution.

What I did, I add css rules in my style.css:

```
#outerImageContainer {
    min-height: 470px !important;
}
```

But still i need to adjust the min-height when the site is resized to smaller view or viewed in mobile devices.

Comment: Another problem is the popup box moves up and down when prev/next is clicked